# powershell converting xml object to string

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing

I am trying to get just the value of the xml to create a directory.  In the first line it will return a table with just the inner xml.  However in the foreach loop it returns @{$_.Value.InnerXML=00000027627-00001} for $loanNumber. How can i convert this to just the number? is there a way i can cast it to a string and then split on the = sign? I ahve been currently trying that way and have not been succeeding.  Is there a better way to just grab the value and not the junk before it?

```
cls

[xml]$file = Get-Content "F:\Peter Test\index.xml"
$hostdirectory = "F:\PShell Testing"

$file.ExportedResult.Docs.ExportedDoc.Doc.UdiValues.UdiValue | ? {$_.Name -eq "Loan Number"} | Select-Object {$_.Value.InnerXML} -Unique | Format-Table


 foreach($loanNumber in $file.ExportedResult.Docs.ExportedDoc.Doc.UdiValues.UdiValue | ? {$_.Name -eq "Loan Number"} | Select-Object {$_.Value.InnerXML} -Unique){
 Write-Host "hey"


    Write-Host $loanNumber
    $hostdirectoryPlusLoan =  $hostdirectory + "\" + $loanNumber
    if(!(test-path $hostdirectoryPlusLoan)){
        New-Item $hostdirectoryPlusLoan -ItemType directory
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert -ExpandProperty in your Select-Object command

```
Select-Object -ExpandProperty {$_.Value.InnerXML} -Unique
```

It should return just the "loannumber" string, "00000027627-00001" in this case.

And you can also do this:

```
  $hostdirectoryPlusLoan =  "$hostdirectory\$loanNumber"
```

instead of

```
  $hostdirectoryPlusLoan =  $hostdirectory + "\" + $loanNumber
```

---

Edit:

You use this at least twice:
    $file.ExportedResult.Docs.ExportedDoc.Doc.UdiValues.UdiValue | ? {$*.Name -eq "Loan Number"} | Select-Object {$*.Value.InnerXML} -Unique

So what about saying

```
# use Select-Object <propertyName> -ExpandProperty -Unique twice to dig down into the nesting
# also, use "Where-Object" for "?"
# and mostly using a variable to hold the list of loan numbers so you don't have to filter and select exactly the same way twice.
$LoanNumberList = $file.ExportedResult.Docs.ExportedDoc.Doc.UdiValues.UdiValue | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Loan Number"} | Select-Object Value -ExpandProperty -Unique | Select-Object InnerXML -ExpandProperty -Unique

# assuming the above works, you can then use $LoanNumberList collection at will:

$LoanNumberList
foreach ($LoanNumber in $LoanNumberList) {
    # do stuff
    }
```

Comment: Adding expandproperty gives me the following error
Select-Object : Property "$_.Value.InnerXML" cannot be found